# Notify Icon appears to be disposed after running batch file

Tags: vb.net, dispose, notifyicon

I have a WinForms application in VB.net with a **NotifyIcon** with **ContextMenu** attached. For some reason when I click the menu item to set the main form as `Me.TopMost = false`, then copy the batch file to the PC and run it, the NotifyIcon seems to get disposed (no longer appears in system tray). This only appears to happen ***intermittently***.... I have no idea what could be causing this.

The reason that I am thinking that the NotifyIcon is disposed is because if I add a `readerNotify.Visible = True` after the operation the icon still does not re-appear. See below for the code

```
     Private Sub ResetWindowsUpdateComponentsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ResetWindowsUpdateComponentsToolStripMenuItem.Click
        'Adds Windows Update Components reset batch file to ProgramData and runs the file
        Dim fileContent As String = My.Resources.WindowsUpdate_Components_Reset
        Dim filename As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\WUCR.bat"

        Me.TopMost = False
        clearWUCache()

        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(filename, fileContent, False, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)

   '**WHERE NOTIFYICON SEEMS TO DIE**

        Dim objProcess As Process = New Process
        objProcess.StartInfo.FileName = filename
        objProcess.Start()
        objProcess.WaitForExit()

        prgBarTemps.Value = 100
        lblStatus.Text = "Windows Update components reset successfully!"

        Me.TopMost = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub clearWUCache()
        Dim wuCacheFolder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows) & "\SoftwareDistribution\Download"
        Try
            WebFixProcesses.deleteFolders(wuCacheFolder)
            WebFixProcesses.deleteFiles(wuCacheFolder)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Dim wuCacheDirect As String = "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download"
            WebFixProcesses.deleteFolders(wuCacheDirect)
            WebFixProcesses.deleteFiles(wuCacheDirect)
            lblStatus.Text = "Press a button to fix problems"
        End Try

    End Sub
```

I must be doing something wrong here in the way I am setting up the batch file in conjunction with setting `Me.TopMost = False` or something like that. Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT:**

Here is some additional info from my Form.Designer **InitializeComponent()** method on the NotifyIcon.

```
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()

'Have omitted other controls    

        Me.readerNotify = New System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(Me.components)

        'readerNotify
                '
                Me.readerNotify.ContextMenuStrip = Me.ContextMenu
                Me.readerNotify.Icon = CType(resources.GetObject("readerNotify.Icon"), System.Drawing.Icon)
                Me.readerNotify.Text = "WebFix"
                Me.readerNotify.Visible = True

     End Sub

     Public WithEvents readerNotify As System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
```

Comment: Are you sure the icon is just not going into the **show hidden icons** button if you don't touch it long enough?

Comment: @Thraka, yup I double checked the hidden icons area by clicking that up arrow next to the time/ date, notification area. It is gone from there as well. But yes I am aware that it is demoted after 45 seconds to this hidden icons area or sometime around that. The only way I can seem to get it back is by re-launching the application.

Comment: Maybe share some more info like some of your form config, the settings you have for the notify icon .. etc

Comment: This post is not related to tag [tag:batch-file], is it?